# How do I access foreach on subarray

Tags: php, foreach, citrix, array-merge

I have an array $registration_fields.
This is split into two subarrays.
I don't know what I'm doing to make this so difficult...
But how could I combine these two foreach statements into one?

```
// For Each #1
foreach($registration_fields->questions as $row)
    //do something
end foreach;

// For Each #2
foreach($registration_fields->fields as $row)
    //do something
end foreach;
```

How can I write this as one foreach statement... and then access the subarrays

ex:

```
//Suggested Combined
//    {allfields} is the part I'm confused on
foreach($registration_fields->{allfields} as $row): $class='';
    //do something
    $inputField = '';
    if(isset($row->question)){
        $inputField = $row->question;
        $class=$class.' question';
    }else{
        $inputField = $row->field;
        $class=$class.' field';
    }
    $output.='<input class="'.$class.'" type="text" size=20  name="'.$inputField.'" id="'.$inputField.'" />';
end foreach;
```

Could someone please suggest how I might improve my code to combine the two foreach? I've taken my best stab at it but am a bit lost.
My second thought is an array merge, but this is already an array --- so that wouldn't make sense right?!
Thanks

Comment: Do each of the sub-arrays have the same number of elements?

Comment: Steinmas -- the number is variable.
Sometimes $registration_fields->fields will be 3 on up to 10 
And $registration->questions could be anywhere from none to unlimited. (probably not more than one question though).
Am I just chasing a wild goose -- aka making this more difficult on my self?
I'm just looking to be a better coder and write cleaner code.

Comment: Is there any specific reason behind why you want to merge them? Otherwise, the two simple loops look pretty cool.

Comment: The answer will depend on what kind of information the "questions" and the "fields" are.  Are they just two different names for the same thing (which would be a poor data design)?  Is there some relationship between them (like many fields per question)?  As another commenter said, what's the motivation to merge them?  If they're different things, process them separately and your code will be clearer.

Comment: You are correct, for the most part - it is two names for the same thing. (out of my control). The exception is that on the off-chance that "questions" contains answers, I'll want to display those as a <select> / dropdown. That I would handle with an if statement. The rest are going to simply be creating a fieldset of dynamic input fields.  ps... different question but on stackoverflow how can I be "Acts7" instead of user925737 or whatever my username shows?